# Temporary table not working in mysql

Tags: mysql

We want to create a temporary table in MySQL.The following query was used but displays message as `"zero rows affected"`

```
create temporary table pv as 
SELECT doc_ref_no FROM `gl_tbl` where doc_ref_no like '%PV%' group b `doc_ref_no`
```

Comment: When you run the query `SELECT doc_ref_no FROM gl_tbl where doc_ref_no like '%PV%' group b doc_ref_no`, will it return any rows?

Comment: Yes it returns 46 rows

Comment: A group by without any aggregation is a bit off. Why not select distinct?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Can you supply sample data?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE pv
AS (SELECT doc_ref_no FROM `gl_tbl` where doc_ref_no like '%PV%' group by `doc_ref_no`)
```

Try this out

Comment: Result is same. "zero rows affected"

Comment: Please check out your database. table get created with data.